# Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field

Tags: php, laravel

#### 解決したいこと

ネットの記事を参考にしながらツイッターのような簡単な投稿サイトを作成しています。
ログイン機能実装中で、ユーザーのダミーデータを作っています。
一覧表示から投稿実装までのCRUDの流れを確認しながら進めて、ログイン機能を追加実装してます。

'user_id'カラムを追加しましたが、下記エラーが出ます。
投稿用のダミーデータは、ログイン機能まで問題なかったです。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `subject`, `message`, `name`) values (2013-02-13 02:11:00, 1972-03-04 01:34:26, つゆが太陽たいの活字かつかった。, ませんなは乗のらな草や、いっぱいしょう」ジョバンニは［＃小書き平仮名ん、ぼんやり白く見えましたちはかすか」ジョバンニは帽子ぼうしろの方を見ているのでした。その鶴つるしは、もうたびはしたような笛ふえを吹ふきなりませんでした。「君たちしっかささぎだねえ」「みんなにうな青じろいろの天上なんだ」カムパネルラにたずねましたりした。「いや森が、なんだねえ」ジョバンニが勢いきないで河かわらっと白服しろはジョバ。, 吉本 京助))
```

#### 該当するソースコード

```php
laravel-app/app/Post.php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * 投稿データを所有するユーザを取得
     */
    public function user()
    {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    
     // 割り当て許可
     protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'subject',
        'message', 
        'user_id',
        #'category_id'
    ];

laravel-app/database/migrations/2021_03_10_101736_create_posts_table.php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('is_deleted', 4)->default('0');
            #$table->integer('category_id');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); #追加
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); #追加
        });
    }

laravel-app/database/seeds/PostsTableSeeder.php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PostsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\Post::class, 50)
            ->create()
            ->each(function ($post) {
                $comments = factory(App\Comment::class, 2)->make();
                $post->comments()->saveMany($comments);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

#### 自分で試したこと

テーブルを書き直したので、migrate:refreshをしました。
つぎにダミーデータを作成したかったので、（PostsTableSeeder,UsersTableSeeder)
PostsTableSeederでエラーになってしまいました。
user.idを追加したので、以前に作った投稿のダミーデータに問題が起きてしまいました。

```php
$ php artisan migrate:refresh
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
$  php artisan db:seed

Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value")
      /var/www/html/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458

  2   PDOStatement::execute()
      /var/www/html/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
end
```

#### 参考記事

ログイン機能
https://note.com/yuki_biwako/n/n696cb97b64b7
投稿関係
https://nodoame.net/archives/11628#vol9

Answer (score 1):

database/factories/PostFactory.phpを修正して、user_idカラムにも値が入るようにしましょう。

参考: [Laravel 7.x データベースのテスト リレーション](https://readouble.com/laravel/7.x/ja/database-testing.html#relationships)

Comment: ありがとうございます！->nullable() と記述したら、エラーが消えました。

Comment: なるほど、ゲスト（未ログインユーザー）も投稿できる仕様ならそれでも問題無さそうですね。

Comment: やはり、仕様を変更したいと考えています。
現在、$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();になっています。

やりたいこと、PostFactoryを編集して、user_idカラムの値が入るようにしたいです。
この２つを試しましたが、上手く入れることが出来ません。他にありますでしょうか？
'user_id'   => $faker->numberBetween($min = 1, $max = 3)
'user_id' => User::factory()->create(),

Comment: 回答にLaravelドキュメントへのリンクを追記しました。ドキュメントに書かれているように
'user_id' => factory(App\User::class),
とするとどうでしょうか。

Comment: ドキュメントのリンク確認できました。リンクの追記ありがとうございます。確認するためにPostPolicyのeditメソッド内で

"dump($user->id);"
"dd($post->user_id);"
"return $user->id === $post->user_id;" にするおとにより値が表示されています。

Comment: すいません、どういう意味ですか？

Comment: 記述前ですと、飛ばしているデータをデバッグで中身を見るとnullになっている箇所がありました。教えていただいた、'user_id' => factory(App\User::class), を書き、（確認のために）PostFactoryでデバッグ(bb)をすることで、1行目にユーザーのID が表示され、2行目にはpostのuser_idが表示されるようになりました。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。問題が解消したということでしょうかね。よかったです^ ^

Comment: Lulucomさん、ありがとうございました。(^^)